# java parse old excel version file use poi and jxl parse all failed

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

at first, this excel file suffix .xls ,I try some way parse file,all failed,please help! below I try:

use  poi `HSSFWorkbook` throw exception:

> org.apache.poi.hssf.OldExcelFormatException: The supplied data appears
>   to be in BIFF3 format. HSSF only supports the BIFF8 format, try
>   OldExcelExtractor

use  poi `XSSFWorkbook` throw exception:

> org.apache.poi.POIXMLException:
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package
>   should contain a content type part [M1.13]

use jxl throw exception:

```
jxl.Workbook rwb = jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
```

> jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream

Comment: It's a magic document, and I've been desperate.

Comment: Do as the first exception suggests, and use `OldExcelExtractor` ?